# Find the smallest sub square matrix that contains all the vowels

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are provided with 2-D Matrix, A, such that

```
    1. A (MxN), is 2-Dimensional Matrix
    2. A[i][j] E [A-Z]
```

you have to find the smallest sub square matrix, such that
it contains all the vowels i.e. {A E, I, O, U}.

```
Input: A[][] -> 
A E I O B   1 2  3  4  5
C D U Z O   6 7  8  9  10
P O A E K  11 12 13 14 15
B R E A K  16 17 18 19 20
```

```
Possible Outputs:
A E I   1 2  3
C D U   5 6  7
P O A   9 10 11

I O B   3 4  5
U Z O   8 9  10
A E K  13 14 15
```

so, size here will be 3x3 square matrix, so it is 3.

Please help me to find out the logic behind this problem.

Comment: There are 5 vowels.  Therefore, all the vowels cannot fit in a 2 x 2 square matrix.  The smallest square matrix you can have is 3 x 3.  You missed EIO, DUZ, OAE as a sub-square matrix.

Comment: but it can be in 4x4 or 5x5 also right..? so how to distinguish  the same?

Comment: Check all 3 x 3 first, then all 4 x 4, then all 5 x 5, until you've reached the size of the matrix.

Comment: but that won't be efficient... need for some efficient algorithm to find this